# JQMigrate to jQuery 1.9, how to find the offending line?

Tags: jquery, html, mediaelement.js, jqmigrate

I am migrating to jQuery 1.9.1, and use the [JQMigrate tool mentioned in the release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/02/04/jquery-1-9-1-released/).

I receive the following warning:

```
JQMIGRATE: $(html) HTML strings must start with '<' character
```

The [explanation by the jQuery folks is quite clear](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md#jqmigrate-html-html-strings-must-start-with--character), **but how to find the offending line?**

The problem seems to be hidden somewhere in a 3rd party lib ([mediaelementjs](http://mediaelementjs.com/)) or in the usage of it. I found this by commenting out calls. But there is quite much going on and I am stuck.

---

**UPDATE:** With the help of Kevin B I found the offending line, it was indeed within mediaelementJS. I the `mediaelement-and-player.js` it was line #3176 which was (note the outer whitespaces)

```
timeAndDurationSeparator: ' <span> | </span> '
```

and is now

```
timeAndDurationSeparator: '<span> | </span>'
```

which works flawlessly now.

In case anyone runs into the same issue, here is the modified file:

- uncompressed
  https://quirli.svn.codeplex.com/svn/webroot/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.js
- minified version
  https://quirli.svn.codeplex.com/svn/webroot/mediaelement/mediaelement-and-player.min.js

I will notify the original author, [John Dyer](http://j.hn/) about this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the right side of your console, under the stack trace. The one line that doesn't say jQuery Migrate or jquery.js is probably the offending line.

For example, on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nrdkF/1/), the offending line is line 24, listed as `(anonymous function)`

Comment: WOW, that did it. Especially thanks for the fiddle, so I was able to study this. My console was too cluttered to spot the line.